# How to run and debug JBoss EAP 6 from Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jboss

I installed JBoss EAP 6.01 on my local computer, and JBoss tools in my eclipse (Juno), I try to access JBoss and debug from within my eclipse, I follow the new server wizard to create and configure sever in eclipse, see attached images:

[image: Create & configure JBoss in eclipse]

[image: Create & configure JBoss in eclipse]

[image]

I then tried to start the server, however, I got error connecting to jmx for JBoss Runtime Server

Can anyone help me figure out why?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear from your question if you want to a) run a fully managed JBoss inside eclipse or b) you want to start Jboss manually and then get eclipse to connect to it.

I'm assuming it's point 'a' and you want eclipse to start and manage jboss eap server for you.

In this case on your second screenshot you need to unselect all the checkboxes and hit next.  Also make sure after the server is created in your servers tab to doubleclick the server to bring up the server configuration page and enter username/password etc.

You should be all set.  Let me know if that works.